# How to popBackStackImmediate() a fragment and pass data from the fragment to another fragment within same activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I want to remove a current fragment in a button click by using popBackstackImmediate() and pass data from the removing fragment to the previous fragment. How can i achieve this?

Comment: where are you using popBackstackImmediate? in the fragment or the activity?

Comment: I'm using from my adapter class which was in a fragment

Answer (score 1):

Fragments generally shouldn't perform fragment transactions on the parent activity's fragment manager. It creates an unnecessary tight coupling in code.

If you reorganize the code the following way, then this solution becomes a bit easier to recognize:

```
class MyFragmentB extends Fragment {
  private Callback mCallback;

  public interface Callback {
    void dataPassback(String somedata);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mCallback = (Callback) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement MyFragmentB.Callback");
    }
  }
  ...
}


class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyFragmentB.Callback {
  @Override
  public void dataPassback(String somedata){
    // 1) pop backstack

    // 2) find fragment A
    MyFragmentA fragmentA;

    fragmentA.setData(someData);
  }
  ...
}
```

Good practices for fragment communication is defined in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html).